# C# UDP Communication-Stack implementation advise

Tags: c#, architecture, udpclient

I am currently writing a C# Program and am struggling a bit with a conceptional question.

A domain of the application is the communication with a Microcontroller via UDP. Therefore I am using the UDPClient and wrote a 'communicator' which does some encoding/decoding, checksum checks, etc.

I need to have some kind of Controller which allows me to send commands to the UDP-Server (the device). Some of them are a single pair of Send/Receive, others are long-running.

I thought about the following implemenation:
[image]

My idea was that every capability of my Microcontroller/UDP-Server is abstracted in a class, which has an 'Execute'-function which subscribes to the 'Receive' of the underlying Communicator and sends it request.

However, I am a bit stuck here: I could wait in the 'Execute ' function of each task(capability) for an event which I trigger in the OnReceive-Handler (or timeout). But that would not work if I one task needs multiple Send/Receive.

So, is there any good Design-Pattern for that? Or does anyone have a good advise on how to implement it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Communicator` and a `CommandExecuter` and share a queue between them. `Communicator` puts every command it receives from `UDP` and goes back to it's duty to receive new commands. `CommandExecuter` is always watching the queue. As long as there is a new command in the queue, takes it and executes it.

Comment: On some commands I get an answer, for example for 'Download' I get a byte-array. I think in your approach the calling class (Controller) would never get that answer

Comment: Yes it can get answer. `CommandExecuter` can execute the command and give the answer back to the `Communicator` and `Communicator` passes the answer to the `Controller`. In this case it is better to have an `ID` for each command so when the `Controller` receives an answer, it can find which command or request it is for.

Comment: But how would that look like? The Controller would create a Command-Object and would put it into the shared Queue. After that, it returns to its normal operation. How would the control flow look like?
Or would it be a proper way to implement each Command as a Task and run inside this Task synchronously?

Comment: `Controller` can send command to `Communicator` and receive response as a `UDP Packet` from it. It means that `Controller` should register on `OnReceive` event of `Communicator`. So `CommandExecuter` executes a command, then gives the response to `Communicator` and `Communicator` passes the response to 'Controller'.